# One shape key, multiple bones driving it

Tags: bones, drivers, shape-keys

I have a character that has 1 shape key that controls the shape of her thighs (both left and right). What I'd like to do is control this shape key with a driver when either the left or right foot is positioned. In other words, when I move the left foot (IK), the "thighs" shape key is activated. When I move the right foot, the same key is activated. Two bones that activate the same shape key driver. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can have one driver only, but in that driver you can set two (or more) variables, one driven by the left bone and one driven by the right bone. The scripted expression could be something like "var1 + var2".

Comment: or `max(var1, var2)` probably.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, thank you. A user over on BlenderArtists helped me as well. Here the settings I used on my character:

[image: Graph Editor Shapekey Driver]